# Is there a way to combine multiple query into one in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am wondering if there is a function in SQL Server or service in Azure to provide an opportunity to combine multiple queries into one. For example,

```
ALTER TABLE1 
    ADD RetailValue AS (CAST(QtyAvailable AS int) * CAST(UnitPrice AS int) * 1.5);
ALTER TABLE2 
    ADD RetailValue AS (CAST(QtyAvailable AS int) * CAST(UnitPrice AS int) * 1.5);
ALTER TABLE3 
    ADD RetailValue AS (CAST(QtyAvailable AS int) * CAST(UnitPrice AS int) * 1.5);
...
```

Is there a way to combine all these together into 1 query that can affect all the tables? the columns will be all same for every table and there are simply just too many tables to do copy and paste.

Thank you!

Comment: Not using `alter` directly, it can alter a single table. You could however use dynamic SQL to build all the alter scripts required.

Comment: Consider not doing this and having one table with an additional column to distinguish records. You can create views on this table if you need to separate them. This tends to be easier to maintain than duplicating things all over the place. You can also go the other way and build a view that `UNION ALL`s separate tables and includes the computed column over that union, if for some reason separate physical tables are a must. Duplication is the greatest enemy of any DB design.

Comment: @Stu thank you! but can dynamic SQL apply to all tables? Could you give me an example? Because all I found need the table name

Comment: @JeroenMostert I understand what you mean. Thank you very much! So is there any external function to achieve this? like Azure or .net 6? (cuz I am using these data to present onto the website I created which is built using .net 6 and razor pages.)

Comment: @Jimmy It doesn't sound like you "understand what [he] mean[s]" at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dynamic SQL you can construct the required `alter` statements and aggregate them into a single string to execute:

```
declare @Sql nvarchar(max);
select @Sql = String_Agg(
  'alter table dbo.' + QuoteName([name]) + ' ADD RetailValue AS (CAST(QtyAvailable AS int) * CAST(UnitPrice AS int) * 1.5); '
  ,'')
from sys.tables where name in ('table1','table2', 'table3')
  and schema_id = Schema_Id('dbo');

print @Sql;
exec (@Sql);
```

See [a demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c992c7d07ed6ef39cf0f50e6c559e5d)

Answer (score 0):

use the stored procedure `sp_msforeachtable` with filtering table.

The placeholder `?' is denoting the table.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable
 @command1 ='ALTER TABLE ? 
    ADD RetailValue AS (CAST(QtyAvailable AS int) * CAST(UnitPrice AS int) * 1.5)'
,@whereand = ' And Object_id In (Select Object_id From sys.objects
Where name in ( ''TABLE1'',''TABLE2''))'
```